# heroku and static files, same 404 error

Tags: python, django, heroku

ive been looking at this for weeks and it has been driving me insane.
it is the usual `404 error` when deploying to heroku.
Can someone advise me what is the purpose of this static file and this complication on heroku?
And secondly, what should I do? I tried so many things already.

settings.py

```
DEBUG = False
PROJECT_ROOT = BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_URL ='/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(os.path.realpath(PROJECT_ROOT), "/static"),)
STATICFILES_FINDERS = ('django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',)
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

wsgi.py

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from mezzanine.utils.conf import real_project_name
from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE",
                      "%s.settings" % real_project_name(appname))

application = get_wsgi_application()
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)
```

yes, I've done `python manage.py collectstatic`
I've also tried adding that in `Procfile`

Comment: Are you tried to use `STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "static"),)`

Comment: @marni yea i tried it. :(

Answer (score 0):

STATIC_ROOT and STATICFILES_DIRS shouldn't be the same. The first is where collectstatic will put files to be served - and where WhiteNoise will serve them from. The second is where they are stored in development.

Comment: oh wait, yeah i tried that too.. I had `STATICFILES_DIRS` as `theme/static` or is it suppose to be something else?